# mat-form-field outline is triggering validation border color change while conditions still false

Tags: angular, outline, angular-reactive-forms, mat-form-field, mat-error

I have the following script to handle validation message:

```
<mat-form-field appearance="outline" floatLabel="never"> 
  <input maxlength="61" #titleInput placeholder="add title"
         matInput id="title" formControlName="name" autocomplete="off"> 
</mat-form-field>
<mat-error  *ngIf="formDTO.get('name').touched && formDTO.get('name').invalid"> 
  <mat-error *ngIf="!!formDTO.get('name').errors?.required">title cannot be blank test</mat-error>
  <mat-error *ngIf="!!formDTO.get('name').errors?.maxlength">title length exceed 60 characters</mat-error>
</mat-error>
```

On the same script I have a button that call another component, a modal that uses typeahead, as follows:

```
<button (click)="addPerson($event)">ADD NEW </button>
```

The validation itself is in the .ts code as follow:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.formDTO = this.fb.group({
      name: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(60)]],
      description: '',
      dueDate: new Date(Date.now()),
      people: this.fb.array([
        this.fb.group({})
      ])
  })
}
```

The button method call an action that opens a modal using @Effect and it is as follows:

```
addPerson(event: MouseEvent) {
    this.store.dispatch(new fromWorkspace.ShowAddPerson());
}
```

The problem I'm having is that when I click a "add person" button  while "title" still empty, the mat-form-field outline for the title turns red.

It does not return the error message, which is the expected behavior, but the outline should remain the same as well.

Is this a bug for mat-form-field or Am I missing something?

Comment: Do you use a `<button>` that maybe does a submit? You could try `<input type="button">`instead. I would guess that you are triggering a submit by mistake and then the validation for `maxlength=61` kicks in.

Comment: so is `formDTO.get('name').touched` truthy in this case?

Comment: ChrisY; I did have a <button type="submit">. I changed it to <button type="button"> and well as <input type="button">  neither worked.

Comment: AJT82: formDTO.get('name').touched is false and mat-error is not triggered. Only the mat-form-field outline is triggered.

Comment: I think the problem is that the form lose focus when the dialog opens. But I don't know how to fix that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out to be pretty simple.
The button that was calling the Dialog:

```
<button (click)="addPerson($event)">ADD NEW </button>
```

need to explicity say type="button" because 'button' by default is of 'submit' type and that was triggering the 'invalid'. So in the end it looked like this:

```
<button type="button" (click)="addPerson($event)">ADD NEW </button>
```